# Issue with mathmode in command

Tags: math-mode

First off I'm new to Latex so my understanding of the Language is quite limited.

I want to print a Formula with cases for the convergence of geometric series i learnt like this(without box):
[image: convergence of geometric series]

Now im getting multiple errors due to the mathmode. I tried a lot of configurations but none of them solved the problem.

I'd be glad to have a solution to my problem and of course, if possible, a good explanation so that i don't trip over the same issue again.

The following code is a sample of my full code including an own command i created:

```latex
\newcommand{\symbonsymb}[2]{\mathrel{\underset{\makebox[0pt]{\mbox{\normalfont\tiny #2}}}{#1}}}

$\sum\limits_{k=k_0}^{$\infty$}x^k=\symbonsymb{lim}{$n\rightarrow\infty$}\frac{x^m-x^{n+1}}{1-x}=
\begin{cases*}
\frac{x^m}{1-x} & x\in]-1,1[\setminus\{0\} \\
divergent & \:else 
\end{cases*}$
```

Thank you in advance for any answers
For Notice:
Im using TexStudio

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... Please post the `MWE` always as in executable format...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\lim` is the default tag available in `TeX`, so no need to redefine it, please refer the updated `MWE`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

$\sum\limits_{k=k_0}^{\infty}x^k=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x^m-x^{n+1}}{1-x}=
\begin{cases}
\frac{x^m}{1-x} & x\in]-1,1[\setminus\{0\} \\
\text{divergent} & \text{else }
\end{cases}
$

\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image]

PS: Sorry few of the handwritten symbols are not able to understand, so just I followed your codes...

Comment: The spacing around `] ... [` is bad.  These should be `\mathopen] ... \mathclose[`.  Also, this would be handled better as a display, with `\[ ... \]` rather than `$` signs.

Comment: What does `MWE` stand for?

Comment: "@Fomps -- An "MWE" is a Minimum (non-)Working Example".  See [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Answer (score 2):

Such a complex formula should be displayed, to begin with.

Next, I'm not sure where you found the code for `\symbonsymb`, but it is wrong under *many* respects. The right command here is `\lim`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\sum_{k=m}^{\infty} x^k
= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x^m-x^{m+n+1}}{1-x}
= \begin{cases}
\dfrac{x^m}{1-x} & x\in \mathopen]-1,1\mathclose[ \\[2ex]
\text{divergent} & \text{else}
\end{cases}
\]

\end{document}
```

For French style intervals, note that you need to use `\mathopen` and `\mathclose` in order to override the standard nature of the brackets.

[image]

I also fixed the math: either you use *k*<sub>0</sub> in both places or *m*. Besides, the series is obviously convergent for *x* = 0, unless the starting index *m* is negative. In that case it's wrong to say that the series is divergent, because it is undefined in the first place.